# matlab comparision difference

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, matlab-coder

`if tf < max(arr)` Vs. `if all(tf < max(arr))`

1. what is the difference between them
2. which one is recommended.
3. are they exactly equivalent?

*I get an error when using matlab coder with the first one though!*

**Edit**

I have

```
if (xf-x0 < small_dist)&&(v0 <= min(vmax0, vmaxf))
```

and considered to change it to

```
leftCmpStatement = all((xf-x0 < small_dist));
rightCmpStatement = all((v0 <= min(vmax0, vmaxf)));
if leftCmpStatement && rightCmpStatement
```

because matlab coder complaining
not that each element is a `1X1 double variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same if `numel(max(arr))` is `1`. If not then if `tf < max(arr)` will only consider the first maximum. But since all the `max(arr)` elements will have the same value it will still work.

However if you used a function that could have returned different values, such as simply
`if tf < arr` vs `if all(tf < arr)` then they are different. `if all(tf < arr)` works as expected, if must be smaller then every element of `arr`.  HOWEVER `if tf < arr` becomes something like `if [true false true false false...]` and (thanks to Amro for pointing this out) Matlab will only conider this true if it is both non-empty and all the elemnets are non-zero. So in my made up example it will be `false`. So the moral of the story is don't give `if` a multi-element matrix in Matlab. So I would go for `if all(tf < max(arr))` just to be consistent with that rule.

Comment: I will test and find out

Comment: The most important part of this is **...Matlab will only consider the first element.**

Comment: @Frederick: that's incorrect, for example `if [true false true], disp('hi'), end` will not evaluate to true. According to `doc if`: "An evaluated expression is true when the result is nonempty and contains all nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise, the expression is false."

Comment: @Amro I tested that and you are correct, but in that case, what is the difference? Because the docs are basically saying they apply the equivalent of and `all` to the conditional anyway?

Comment: @Dan: that's not exactly it either; note that `all([])` is `true` but according to the previous quote `if [], 1, end` evaluates to false... I know, this is a confusing part of MATLAB :) There are more of these "weird" cases! Just to remind you, the OP was specifically talking in the context of MATLAB Coder, which might have stricter conditions on what it accepts